# Sharepoint 2010 powershell add-spsolution access denied

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to do a test deployment to a client server.

The site collection backup completed without error.

When trying to add a spsolution I get an 'Access Denied' error. I'm adding it with the following:

Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\webpartgallery.wsp

I'm a farm admin, site collection admin, and a shell admin. I'm NOT an administrator on the server, so I can't run powershell as an admin.

Is this a necessity, or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I had them temporarily add me as a administrator, and adding/installing the solution worked. Unfortunately, due to their security policies, this cannot remain in place.

Comment: I also had to logout / login, so to clean up all the cache.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add solutions you need to be local administrator on top of shell admin. Run the shell as administrator.

**Edit:**

As I said in comments, I can't find a specific requirement specified on TechNet, but I did a test on one of my farms:

- First I added a brand new user to my AD.
- As being member of the AD the users only right on my farm server is that its part of domain users, and hence part of local User group.
- I fired up a SP2010 administration shell using Run as different user (right click on shell) and logged in as my new user. Already as I started up I got some errors because of lack of access (The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.)
- I tried adding solution and got:

  *Add-SPSolution : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate permissions to access the database before trying again.*
- I now gave test user farm admin privileges and started up a new shell. Still got the same error.
- I ran another
  Shell as my farm admin (if logged in
  as account remember to use Run As
  Administrator if you have UAC
  enabled). Here I added my test user
  as Shell Admin
- I now started a new shell with my test user. No errors while loading, but when I tried adding I got the same error as you:

  *Add-SPSolution: Access Denied*
- I then added the test user to the local administrator group and opened up a new shell.
- When adding the user I could add the user without issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have a reference for this? I can't find anything. I'll need to show our client.

Comment: I cant find it on TechNet, but found several references to this on MS fora and blogs. I did a test also on my local farm, se updated answer

Comment: Thank you Anders, I appreciate the effort. Odd that MS lets a farm/shell admin completely blow away a site collection but not install a solution. I suppose they are farm scoped, but can they really do more harm than deleting site collections??

Comment: in stsadm it was the same: you needed to be local admin to use it for most purposes. being a farm admin will give you several permissions in registry and on file system (see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx) so since this could be a file permission issue i tried uploading WSP from  %windir%\temp (that WSS_ADMIN_WPG should have full control over) but still no dice, so i dont think theres any workaround on this unfortunately

Comment: Here is the reference for permissions needed to deploy solutions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx "You must be a member of the Administrators group on any computer on which you run Windows PowerShell."

Comment: I try add the user to the local administrator group but the server is Domain Controller.
Thuan Nguyen SharePoint MVP @nnthuan says 
**"You CAN'T create a local account on the domain controller."**

Comment: local administrator means that you need to add the user to the "administrators" group on each of the servers in the farm, **not** domain administrator!

Answer (score 2):

Per [my own blog](http://developer.mintrus.com/2012/09/sharepoint-2010-cannot-access-the-local-farm/), if you’re encountering the following error, when trying to run a powershell script, you may not have sufficient permissions on the database.

> Get-SPWeb : Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm
>   is properly configured, currently available, and that you have the
>   appropriate permission to access the database before trying again.

The issue can be remedied with a few quick powershell commands.

Perform the following script in the SharePoint Management Shell, as a farm administrator and it will remove the error.

```
Get-SPDatabase | Add-SPShellAdmin SomeDomain\SomeUserName
```

This will grant the user both access to the configuration database as well as the content database.

Alternatively, you can revoke that granted access with the opposite command.

```
Get-SPDatabase | Remove-SPShellAdmin SomeDomain\SomeUserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what do you do when you are running everything on a Domain Controller that is also the host server for Active Directory Domain Services.   When you run as Administrator you are not using the SharePoint 2010 Farm account.

So frustrating.

Comment: any solution about it if  you are running everything on a Domain Controller ?

Comment: I try add the user to the local administrator group but the server is Domain Controller.
Thuan Nguyen SharePoint MVP @nnthuan says 
**"You CAN'T create a local account on the domain controller."**

Answer (score 0):

It's not a permissions issue. If you're trying to Run As a Different User, it will always fail no matter what.

That was my problem.

Try "run as administrator" instead.