# Is it possible to reuse views you have created?

Tags: 2010

I created a View for a document List. Now I want to reuse this view all over my Share Point Farm. I don't want to reproduce the view again and again is it possible to reference that view or at least copy paste it through my Farm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The View is bound to a list. There is no way to copy it and pass it over to anther list. However, you may save the list as template and create new list from that template. The newly created list will have the view. If the list already exists and you want to have the new view in them, then you may like to automate it through PowerShell or a console app.

Comment: Can I only Automate this If I have full Access to the SharePoint Farm?

Comment: You definitely need higher permissions that a normal user. Check this for more information: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60204/i-dont-have-permissions-to-use-sharepoint-powershell-what-to-do