# Access denied in powerschell script for Add SPSolution

Tags: powershell, deployment, farm-solution

I have a Windows Server 2012 Standard, named DC. This server is a Domain Controller.
I have Sharepoint 2013.

The domain is DEVRSG.COM.
I log on in DC machine using DEVRSG\Administrator, is Domain Administrator.

The user for execute powershell that I use is DEVRSG\svcwss.

The user DEVRSG\svcwss:

- belongs to WSS_ADMIN_WPG group
- belongs to Administrators group (devrsg.com/Builtin)
- belongs to Active Directory - Domain Users
- is a Farm Administrator
- is SPShellAdmin (I use command Get-SPShellAdmin)
- has permissions on Sharepoint_Config and Sharepoint_AdminContent_{GUID} databases.

Note:
I try add the user to the local administrator group but the server is Domain Controller.
Thuan Nguyen SharePoint MVP @nnthuan says 
**"You CAN'T create a local account on the domain controller."**

Run the Sharepoint 2013 Management Shell as the user DEVRSG\svcwss.

I try to execute a powershell script for deploy a WSP (Add SPSolution, features, etc).

I get "Access denied." error

```
WriteTraceErrorException : Message: Access denied.. StackTrace:    at
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolution.EnsureSolutionOperationPermission()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionCollection.Add(String path, String name, UInt32 lcid, Boolean
isRestore)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionCollection.Add(String path, UInt32 lcid)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPNewCmdletBase1.InternalProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
At C:\Temporal\Instalacion_DeploySharepointEscritorio_Pub\common.ps1:282 char:3
+         WriteTraceErrorException($_.Exception)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,WriteTraceErrorException
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to open and run management shell as administrator? ( Right click, 'Run as Administrator' )

Comment: What about the farm admin account which run the Timer Services, did you try to install with that account. check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/sharepoint-2010-powershell-add-spsolution-access-denied?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

as user19952 noted, run powershell as admin.

**Problem:**

Your running an admin level task, the user DEVRSG\svcwss your user doesn't have the sufficient levels to run the dll for Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.

**solution:**

click **start** -> click **all programmes** -> click **Microsoft sharepoint 2013 products** -> right click **sharepoint 2013 management shell** -> run as admin.

---

or win 8 style:

hover top right -> click **search button** and search for **sharepoint 2013 management shell** -> click **sharepoint 2013 management shell** -> bottom screen menu click on **run as admin**.